# Why won't the Tkinter window update when I try to add buttons and titles and so on?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, inheritance

```
class UI(Tk):
def __innit__(self):
    super().__innit__()
    self.title('Planetery Motion Simulator')
    self.button = Button(self, text='Hello')
    self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=3)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = UI()
    app.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to create a simple GUI for a planetery motion simulator project I am doing but I can't seem to get it working despite my code being almost identical to anything I've found on the web.

I was hoping the title would change and a button would appear just so that I could make sure I had used the inheritance correctly.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you have?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small typo in your code: you have the method `__innit__` (with two n) instead of `__init__` (with one n).

The corrected code should be:

```py
from tkinter import *

class UI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Planetery Motion Simulator')
        self.button = Button(self, text='Hello')
        self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=3)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = UI()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oops, a touch embarrassing. Thank god you've got better eyes than I.

Comment: Great that it's now working! Just note, if the answer helped you, you could accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error in:

```
def __innit__(self):
```

It should be:

```
def __init__(self):
```

That’s probably why your class isn't being instantiated correctly

Comment: Also there's the same issue in the super call: instead of super().__innit__() there has to be super().__init__()

Comment: Of course, how could I be so blind. Thank you, I thought I was going crazy !